# SSRS report returns different results in Chrome vs IE/Edge/Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, google-chrome, reporting-services

I'm having some issues with a report deployed to an SSRS 2016 server. 
When the report is run in IE, Edge or previewed in VS it returns the correct result (some sales data for the current month), but when the same report is run in Chrome it returns values for the whole year.

I've searched for thoroughly for a resolution but was unable to find anything. I did find a few posts here and elsewhere regarding compatability issues between Chrome and SSRS 2016, but the resolutions (using various Chrome extensions), did not work. Using an extension is not really the solution that I want, as I'm more concerned about users viewing reports in Chrome and seeing incorrect results.

### Additional info:

+This is a report I have inherited and did not design.

+Report has a number of parameters, some hidden, some not.

+Report contains 18 datasets.

+There are some textboxes with actions in the report, each of which execute the report with different parameters (eg last quarter, YTD).

+When certain actions are executed, the report returns the below error. This only happens when using Chrome.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot read the next data row for the dataset ConversionRates. >(rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
>   For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the >local server machine, or enable remote errors

+The dataset described in the above error is not the same every time the report is run.

### What I've tried already:

+Various Chrome extensions (more as a test than a solution), these made no difference.
+Searching this site / Google for suggestions but to no avail.

### What I would like to achieve:

> I would like to know how I can ensure that the correct results can be
>   returned in Chrome for any user, without having to perform any action
>   on each user's machine.

I realize this is not much to go on, but I'm hoping someone else has encountered the same error. I suspect it's something to do with rendering in Chrome but I can't figure it out, so any suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks v much

Comment: As a quick question, but how are you entering the dates? I (in the past) asked our users to avoid using Chrome for reports, as at least it used to always format dates in `MM/dd/yyyy` from the date picker. As i work in Britain, the "correct" format would be `dd/MM/yyyy`; thus if you enter the dates manually, entering `01/01/2018` and `07/01/2018` is going to get you very different results, purely based on the Browser's date format preference. (One running 01 Jan to 07 Jan, and the other 01 Jan to 01 Jul). Also, what version of SSRS? Chrome wasn't officially supported by SSRS until SSRS 2016.

Comment: @Larnu Brilliant! Thanks v much, the problem is the default date format (I also work in the UK). I made the parameters visible, redeployed and could see that they were calculated differently in each browser. For any other users encountering this problem, a possible solution is to use dataset based defaults instead of SSRS expressions.

Comment: To be honest, I think the better solution is don't use Chrome. :) Like I said Chrome wasn't officially supported until SSRS 2016, and I still find it to be quirky on the later version. On the other hand, IE and Firefox are both very reliable; Edge however is not (ironically).